# wireless capability turned off frequently and automatically happening

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I am having this problem I use a USB wireless adapter and in my network frequently the connection disconnects and I 
open Network and Internet --->Network Connections look for adapter Wifi3 right click on it chose diagnose option and then Windows network diagnostics run for some time then it fixes the problem as in following screenshot
[image: wireless capability turned off]

after running this fix things work smooth for a couple of minutes but again in a few minutes the connection breaks and I get an ugly yellow icon at the bottom which shows I have limited connection with no internet connectivity. Then I have to re run windows diagnostics again and the solution is same. 
What could be a reason for this problem how do I permanently fix this?
I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit.
It is an HP 15 Notebook PC (laptop).

Following is the USB wifi adaptor I am using https://eu.dlink.com/uk/en/products/dwa-131-wireless-n-nano-usb-adapter

Here is the output of command netsh wlan show drivers
[image]

Comment: Try to change to another wifi channell (11 is said to be the best). You may also try another wireless adapter.

Comment: I live in a hostel and changing channel is not possible. The same adapter is working fine when I tested in a friends laptop who lives in a room near to wifi router in campus.

Comment: You might be too far from the transmitter, or there might be electrical interference. You should talk with the hostel staff. If their transmitter is currently wasting half its power on the outside world, maybe you can use a zero-cost solution [like this](https://superuser.com/a/492003/8672).