# Methods to stream desktop to laptop

Tags: networking, ethernet, streaming

Due to unrelated circumstances I may need to move my desktop into a room where space is an issue and it is not possible to add another dedicated computer screen. I would like to stream my desktop to my laptop and ***continue using my laptop keyboard*** along with a USB mouse that can be attached to either device.

My main issue is with the home network. There is only one wall ethernet port that the router connects to and it's in a far off room and I am **not** going to tear up the house running an ethernet cable between rooms.

I've been using Parsec but the wifi simply isn't strong enough and creates unbearable lag. I've also been reading about powerline adapters but I am unsure about the quality and reliability of the signal nor if the house will even support these as some sites state that older houses simply won't support it.

Ideally I would like something where I can plug an ethernet cable directly from my desktop PC to my laptop and stream between the two. From what I've read Parsec doesn't support this and I am unable to find any alternatives.

Does anyone have *any* ideas for how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Confused: You want an ethernet cable but you can't run it? Why do you need to tear up the house for that? Why can't you try powerline adapters and return them if they don't work? Same for stronger wifi routers?

Comment: Ethernet would be better and much more reliable than wifi yes. I'm definitely not running any cable through the walls and the rooms are both on separate floors as far away as possible from each other. There's simply no way I could route a cable up the stairs without it being in the way and a tripping hazard. 

We're still very much on lockdown here and buying and returning equipment would mean waiting for delivery and dealing with whatever Amazon's return policy is and if there's a simple way to do this without new equipment I'd rather do that.

Comment: If you are limited to trying out software, then try [TeamViewer & alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/). Wifi can also be [boosted](https://superuser.com/questions/490815/what-are-the-best-wifi-settings-for-my-situation) using aluminum foil.